# Why are closed questions not deleted?

Tags: discussion

Why are (old) closed questions not deleted if these questions are against the Q&A-format. Wouldn't it be in the intrest of the site's principles?

I'm especially addressing locks for "historical significance". If these questions are bad- as the note says - why do they still exist?

Comment: They **are** deleted, if they have a negative score.

Comment: The note itself explicitly tells you why they exist and aren't deleted.  You only need to read it.

Comment: Seems to there is an answer lurking right there in your question, in regards to the locked questions.

Comment: They exist for their historical significance. They aren't bad, they are still useful. But they are violating the on-topic rules now and thus they are closed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters If people upvote the question but it is off-topic it is not deleted.

Comment: @PatrickHofman But why are they allowed and not new questions?

Comment: @JimmyT. Well, technically a post can have upvotes and still have a negative score, so long as there are more downvotes.

Comment: They were once allowed. These were filtered out as useful but not what they want for future questions.

Comment: @JimmyT. Again, read the notation.  It explains exactly why they are allowed to stick around.

Comment: @Servy New questions could also have this reason to exist. But they aren't allowed. Where is the difference?

Comment: @JimmyT. There isn't one.  If a new question happens to meet the criteria for a historical lock it can get one.  There is nothing about the notation that states that the question needs to be more than a certain age.  Of course, questions that are just asked basically never actually do meet those criteria, as it's such a high bar.

Comment: @Servy They can't get the lock because they would need the upvotes which they don't get because they are closed before. I mean, if those questions where asked today they would be closed or even deleted. So why?

Comment: @JimmyT. Questions don't get locked because they have upvotes.  Perhaps you need to read the notation again.  Also, closed questions *can* get upvotes, so that's not even true.

Comment: @Servy Locked questions can not be answered and therefore there is no knowledge which allows the question to stay. It's a doom loop.

Comment: @JimmyT. Correct, locked questions cannot accumulate knowledge.  You also seem to be under the impression that you have some implicit right to be able to ask off topic questions and have them be able to get a historical lock.  What makes you think you have that right?

Comment: @Servy I don't think that my questions deserve that right but it seems  hypocritical to me. If a question is allowed simply depends on its age then.

Comment: It isn't "simply depends on its age". The number of views and votes are also taken into account when moderators lock a question for historical significance. What you are not seeing is the much larger number of such questions that have, in fact, been deleted.

Comment: @Oded Yes, but new ones can't get those views and votes. And many is not all.

Comment: @JimmyT. It seems hypocritical to you that questions that are off topic but are of significant value to the community be kept around while questions that are off topic but that are of negative value to the community are not kept around?  That just seems sensible to me.  Trying to either delete valuable content or allow harmful content merely to remove an exception from the rules and make the rules more "elegant" doesn't seem like it's beneficial to the community.

Comment: @JimmyT. **So what**.  You just finished stating that you don't think you have an implicit right to ask a new question that can get a historical lock.  If it's impossible for you to create a question with enough view, votes, and otherwise value, to get a historical lock *then that's just the way it is*.  As you said, you don't have the an implicit right to do that.  If you can't do that, thing, then you just can't.

Comment: @JimmyT. - You seem to miss the "historical" in "historical significance". A new question cannot have "historical significance". I truly don't get your beef with the fact that attitudes change and the notion that "what was OK then isn't now" is.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is here regarding the historical locks, frankly. The word "historical" means "happened in the past". The "historical lock" means "This post happened in the past, when it may have been on topic, but it's not on topic now. Because it still has value, even though it's not appropriate any longer, we'll lock it to keep that valuable content around". What part of that is difficult? A new question doesn't qualify for a "historical lock", because **it didn't happen in the past, when it was probably on-topic**. It happened **now**, and so **historical** can't apply.

Answer (score 5):

Not every closed question needs to be deleted. We've had many arguments about this over the years, but my personal opinion is that deleting closed questions with informative, useful answers does not serve our goal of making the Internet a better place.

Some people share this opinion, but others believe that all closed and off topic questions should be deleted. These two groups come into conflict around certain older, popular, but no longer on-topic questions. This leads to cycles of deletion and undeletion, and distracting arguments. We lock certain posts with a historical notice to end these fights. The notice clearly conveys that there is some value in the question and its answers, but that it does not fit the scope of the site at present. We don't use this often, though.

If a question is closed, is it clearly marked as being inappropriate for the site in one way or another. I feel that's enough to indicate that questions like it are no longer welcome here. If there's nothing of value within a question (upvoted answers, etc.), it's usually removed by the system automatically. For the rest, I lean towards wanting to preserve good content, even if it or the question it's on happens to fall outside of current site guidelines.